# Facebook sdk v2.8 send notifications

Tags: php, android, ios, facebook-graph-api, notifications

I want to send notifications from a web service to facebook users of my mobile app, which is authenticated by Facebook. But when I do the request, Facebook returns me this error: 
OAuthException: (#200) Only web canvas apps can send app notifications

It could be that Facebook only avoid send notifications for a Facebook Canvas?
[Solution for old versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13262965/cant-send-fb-notifications-with-new-api)
But Facebook canvas does not exist in the last version of api graph (v2.8). Now, Facebook Canvas are a facebook product for ads. Facebook game appears where the product FB canvas appeared before.
Should I create a Facebook game to be able to send notifications from my mobile app?
Any help please?

Thanks

Comment: "Facebook Canvas are a facebook product for ads"? what? no. either way, you should not use notifications for external websites, that´s not what they are for.

Comment: Yes, what used to be the Canvas platform is now called Facebook Web Games.